# Return column for the first occurrence of "1" in row

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, multiple-instances

I have a dataframe as below :

When there is change in column "col", I need to scan the columns, cola, colb, colc, cola1,colb1,colc1 for the first occurance of "1".

Then, the condition cola==cola1==1 or  colb==colb1==1 or colc==colc1==1 should satisfy, and return that column name in the new column "New_col"

Input:

```
     cola   colb  colc  cola1 colb1 colc1  col
      0       0    0     0     0     0      18
      1       0    0     1     1     0      18
      1       0    0     1     1     0      18
      1       0    0     1     1     0      18
      1       0    0     1     1     0      18
      0       0    0     0     0     0      24
      0       1    0     0     1     0      24
      0       1    0     0     1     0      24
      0       1    0     0     1     0      24
      0       1    0     0     1     0      24
      0       0    0     0     1     0      10
```

Expected Output:

```
     cola   colb  colc  cola1 colb1 colc1  col  New_col
     0       0    0     0     0     0      18    
     1       0    0     1     1     0      18
     1       0    0     1     1     0      18
     1       0    0     1     1     0      18
     1       0    0     1     1     0      18
     0       0    0     0     0     0      24     cola
     0       1    0     0     1     0      24
     0       1    0     0     1     0      24
     0       1    0     0     1     0      24
     0       1    0     0     1     0      24
     0       0    0     0     1     0      10    colb
```

Comment: What if all 3-conditions satisfies. what output you want? is there any precedence?

Comment: I dont understand why is output in its row. Because it seems it is first occurence of previous group. Can you explain more?

Comment: In the 5th row, the value of column "col" is changing from 0 to 1. Hence i need to scan all the other columns above this row for the first occurrence of "1". 
And the output to be returned should satisfy:
Only when cola and cola1 = 1 or colb and colb1 =1 or colc and colc1 =1.

Comment: We need the answer to the first comment.

Comment: I would guess it should output the first column that equals 1. That's the question in the title. But the example output does not make any sense, since in row 6 there is no column which equals 1 and in the last row col does not equal 1.

Comment: For the first comment,
At any given point of time, either cola, colb or colc, will have the value 1.
That's the assumption.
Next condition, should be, when cola = cola1 =1 then return cola
or
colb = colb1 = 1, then return colb
or 
colc = colc1 =1 , then return colc.

And this condition is looked, whenever there is change in column "col".

Comment: I have edited , for clarity

Answer (score 1):

An almost complete answer:

**First**, calculate the conditions you're using and put them in columns:

```
df['conda'] = (df['cola'] == 1) & (df['cola1'] == 1)
df['condb'] = (df['colb'] == 1) & (df['colb1'] == 1)
df['condc'] = (df['colc'] == 1) & (df['colc1'] == 1)

df['anycond'] = df['conda'] | df['condb'] | df['condc']
```

**Second**, define a function that takes the first true condition (of `a`, `b`, `c`) as soon as any condition is true:

```
def get_first_condition(g):
    if not g['anycond'].any():
        return np.nan
    mask = g.loc[g['anycond'], ['conda', 'condb', 'condc']].iloc[0].values
    return np.array(['cola', 'colb', 'cocl'])[mask][0]
```

**Third**, apply to the dataframe grouped by `col`:

```
df.groupby('col').apply(get_first_condition)

col
10     NaN
18    cola
24    colb
```

**Fourth**, just use this result to populate the new column. You will need to do some shifting.